# Java: Is there a way to print to a receipt printer via USB on Windows using ESC commands?

Tags: java

I have been stuck on this problem for a few months and I still can't get it working. How do I start communicating, sending commands, and printing to a receipt printer that is connected via USB?

Comment: I think there should be a driver to make it as a COM printer and probably you can communicate with printer but not sure this approach is good.

Answer (score 2):

I know it may be late, but one solution I've tried on windows is to install the receipt printer using the Generic/Text Only Driver.  Then share it.  Then mapping it to a LPT port, using a net use command:

```
net use \\%computername%\[sharename] LPT1: /persistent:yes
```

You can look up more options for net use here:

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_use.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll pile on the late-answer bandwagon. How about the [jUSB](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-usb/index.html) project?

Comment: thank you. but I have tried jUSB. It doesn't seems to work for me.